# Why do I get "Static member '...' cannot be used on instance of type '...'" error?

Tags: swift, static, compiler-errors

Here is a straightforward use of a static member inside an instance method:

```
public struct RankSet {
    private let rankSet : UInt8
    static let counts : [UInt8] = [
        0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4,
        ... // More of the same
        4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8
    ]
    public var count : Int {
        get {
            // The error is on the following line
            return Int(counts[Int(rankSet)])
        }
    }
}
```

Swift produces the following error:

> Static member `'counts'` cannot be used on instance of type `'RankSet'`

[image: Screenshot]

Since static members are shared among all instances of my class, all instance members, including `count`, should have access to the `counts` member. What is going on here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The error message is misleading: static members can be accessed from any piece of code that has proper visibility to them, which includes instance methods.

However, Swift does not provide a short name access to static members from instance methods - a common feature of many other programming languages. This is what is causing the error above.

Swift insists on fully qualifying names of static members, as follows:

```
public var count : Int {
    get {
        return Int(RankSet.counts[Int(rankSet)])
        //         ^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```