# Call static method without repeating the class name

Tags: swift

Is it possible, in Swift, to call a `static` (or `class`) method/attribute without writing the class name (from an instance method)?

```
class Foo {
  class func someValue() -> Int {
    return 1337
  }

  func printValue() {
    print(Foo.someValue())
    print(type(of: self).someValue())

    print(Self.someValue()) // error: use of unresolved identifier 'Self'
  }
}
```

So far, I've found a workaround with a protocol / typealias:

```
protocol _Static {
  typealias Static = Self
}


class Foo: _Static {
  class func someValue() -> Int {
    return 1337
  }

  func printValue() {
    print(Static.someValue()) // 1337
  }
}
```

but I was wondering if there were a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way - [Swift wants you to fully qualify names of static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271907/335858).

Comment: Here's hoping that [universal `Self`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) will be implemented soon (proposal so old that it's using `.dynamicType` rather than `type(of:)`)...

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for that. Apparently this issue as low priority because it's not ABI related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Swift 5.1 this code no longer produce an error.

```swift
class Foo {
  class func someValue() -> Int {
    return 1337
  }

  func printValue() {
    print(Foo.someValue())
    print(type(of: self).someValue())

    print(Self.someValue()) // ok
  }
}
```